# How to make my code to display only one item from pandas dataset?

Tags: python, pandas

Code sample :

```
def parse_first_name_female(name):
    first = name.str.extract(r"Mrs\.\s+[^(]*\((\w+)", expand=False)
    first.loc[first.isna()] = name.str.extract(r"\.\s+(\w+)", expand=False)
    return first

female_names = parse_first_name_female(dataset.loc[dataset['Sex']=='female', 'Name'])
```

This code returns:

```
print(female_names)

1       Florence
2          Laina
3           Lily
8      Elisabeth
9          Adele
         ...    
880      Imanita
882        Gerda
885     Margaret
887     Margaret
888    Catherine
```

I need this code just first name to return('Florence')

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `.iloc`?

```
def parse_first_name_female(name):
    first = name.str.extract(r"Mrs\.\s+[^(]*\((\w+)", expand=False)
    first.loc[first.isna()] = name.str.extract(r"\.\s+(\w+)", expand=False)
    return first

female_names = parse_first_name_female(dataset.loc[dataset['Sex']=='female', 'Name'])
print(female_names.iloc[0])

# Output
Florence
```

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Braund, Mr. Owen Harris', 'Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)', 'Heikkinen, Miss. Laina', 'Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)', 'Allen, Mr. William Henry', 'Moran, Mr. James', 'McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J', 'Palsson, Master. Gosta Leonard', 'Johnson, Mrs. Oscar W (Elisabeth Vilhelmina Berg)', 'Nasser, Mrs. Nicholas (Adele Achem)'],
                   'Sex': ['male', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'female'],
                   })
```

Comment: @Edward. Is it what you expect?